# Set coordinates system for the notebook

Tags: coordinate-transformation

Is there a way to set the coordinates system globally, for the whole notebook? Back in earlier versions, there was SetCoordinates[] from the Vector Analysis package...

I would like to be able to set the coordinates system so that expressions of Div, Curl, etc using the compact notation with the Del symbol are correct.

Thanks in advance.